# Appending a big number of nodes to an xml tree

Tags: c, libxml2

I'm using [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) via C, to work with xml file creation and parsing. Until recently everything worked smoothly, but a case emerged where a single tree has a subnode, lets call it `S`, with approximately 200,000 children. This case works surprisingly slow and I suspect the function :

```
xmlNewChild(/**/);
```

which I'm using to build the tree, has to iterate over every child of `S` to add one more child. Since a function that also accepts a hint (a pointer to the last added function) doesn't seem to exist, is there a better way to build the tree (maybe a **batch build** method) ? In case such numbers are insignificant and I should search for deficiencies elsewhere, please let me know.

Comment: *libxml2* stores a pointer to the last child of every node, so `xmlNewChild` should run in constant time. I suspect your performance problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, rather than keeping the entire XML in memory with xmlTree, you may want to use a combination of libxml's xmlReader and xmlWriter APIs.  They're both streaming, so it won't have to keep the entire document in memory and won't have any scaling problems based on the number of elements.

Examples of both xmlReader and xmlWriter can be found here:

http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html